# how to pass header in retrofit 1.9 API

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit

Requirement->

To get list of Objects Using GET Request:

passing Request headers:

X-ACCESS-TOKEN = Token received after successful sign in

X-USER-EMAIL = Email used in login.

I am using this code to login->

```
private void normalLoginToServer() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = GeneralUtil.createProgressDialog(this, "Logging into app..");
    progressDialog.show();

Instead of using JSONObject, i need to pass Request Headers.
in a below Astrike code. how to pass Headers.? please help me.

    ***JSONObject outer_body = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    try {
        body.put(Constants.USER_EMAIL, _emailText.getText().toString().trim());
        body.put(Constants.USER_PWD, _passwordText.getText().toString().trim());

        outer_body.put(Constants.USER, body);***

        try {
            TypedInput typedInput = new TypedByteArray("text/plain", outer_body.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

            apiService.loginToServer(typedInput, new Callback<UserInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void success(UserInfo response, Response response2) {
                    int status = response2.getStatus();
                    switch (status) {
                        case 200:
                            if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            if (response == null)
                                return;
                            String status1 = response.getStatus();
                            if (status1.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Successful login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Data data = response.getData();
                                User user = data.getUser();
                                String token = user.getAccess_token();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else if (status1.contains("failure")) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Username not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            break;

                        case 500:
                            Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.server_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (retrofitError != null) {
                        if (retrofitError.getKind() != null) {
                            if (retrofitError.getKind().equals(RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK)) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Check your network connection and try again later",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else if (retrofitError.getResponse() != null) {
                            if (retrofitError.getResponse().getStatus() == 500) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.server_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advenced.!!

Comment: do you need to pass dynamic headers or static ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Header` in your retrofit api interface.  For example, something like:

```
void loginToServer(@Header("your_header") String yourHeaderValue, Callback<UserInfo> callback);
```

Comment: But how i will access in TypedInput.?
TypedInput typedInput = new TypedByteArray("text/plain", outer_body.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

Comment: means after successful login, i am getting: { "status": "success"," info": "login successful", "user":{"access_token": "fdfdfgfgfgf", "email":"test001@test.com"} now i have to fatch User data based on "access-token" and "email". so for that i need to pass dynamic request parameter. X-ACCESS-TOKEN = Token received after successful sign in X-USER-EMAIL = Email used in login so can put your answer/code in above code, so it can be easily understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to pass static headers(those who won't change for a individual requests).
for example this code adds cache control header to /tasks request

```
public interface UserService {  
    @Headers("Cache-Control: max-age=640000")
    @GET("/tasks")
    List<Task> getTasks();
}
```

and if you need to pass dynamic headers (those changing on individual requests)

```
public interface UserService {  
    @GET("/tasks")
    List<Task> getTasks(@Header("Content-Range") String contentRange);
}
```

More on [Retrofit Add Custom Request Header](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header)

Comment: TypedInput typedInput = new TypedByteArray("text/plain", outer_body.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
But how i will access in TypedInput.?

Comment: means after successful login, i am getting:
{ "status": "success"," info": "login successful", "user":{"access_token": "fdfdfgfgfgf", "email":"test001@test.com"} 
now i have to fatch User data based on "access-token" and "email". so for that i need to pass dynamic request parameter.
X-ACCESS-TOKEN = Token received after successful sign in 

X-USER-EMAIL = Email used in login 

so can put your answer/code in above code, so it can be easily understandable.

Comment: im not getting this... are you asking how to add my answer to your code. or something else? please be as clear as you can.

Comment: yes, i want you to add your answer to my code. because i am not able to further proceed. thanks..!!

Comment: okay. In your `ApiService` Class edit the method called `loginToServer` to have the argument `@Header("Cache-Control") String contentRange` like this `loginToServer(@Header("Cache-Control") String cacheControl)` then when you call it in your above code do this `apiService.loginToServer("max-age=640000"...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147461/discussion-between-henok-getachew-and-ashish-patel).